# What to do with DLLs when deploying to Azure from Git Repository

Tags: c#, git, deployment, azure

I am trying to deploy a C# app to azure using a git repo but it fails saying:

```
The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Currently, all DLL's are excluded from the repository.  I don't want to include all of these DLL's because it will make my repo huge.  Is there are way around having to do this?

Comment: Where are you deploying? Azure Websites or Azure Cloud Services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is turn on NuGet package restore on your solution (right click on the solution in VS to find the option).

Then you can exclude all the binaries using .gitignore. See [this repo](https://github.com/KuduApps/Mvc4Application) for an example.

Comment: Duh! Figured this out a little while ago.